# How to define a relational condition between symbols in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to calculate the limit of the `exp((a-b)*x)` function to `x` tending to infinity, where symbols a and b were defined as real and positive:

```
a = Symbol('a', real=True, positive=True)
b = Symbol('b', real=True, positive=True)
```

However, the limit depends on the difference `a-b`. If `a<b`, the limit is zero. If `a=b`, the limit is 1. If `a>b`, the limit is infinity. How to set these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `d = a - b` then define a Piecewise with the limits for different conditions:

```
>>> oolim = lambda A: limit(exp(A*x),x,oo)
>>> f = Piecewise((oolim(d), a>b), (oolim(0), Eq(a,b)), (oolim(-d),True)); f
Piecewise((oo, a > b), (1, Eq(a, b)), (0, True))
```

You could substitute a value for `a` and/or `b` into `f` and the expression will evaluate/update:

```
>>> f.subs({a:3, b:5})
0
```